# MongoDB docker container - Volume set to existing database

Tags: mongodb, docker

I have an existing MongoDB 4.0 running via homebrew service. In this service, I have multiple databases, working as expected.

The thing is, I want to update it to MongoDB 4.2, but I want to run it via Docker. Right now I have this configuration:

```yaml
version: "3.9"
services:
    mongo-4.2:
      container_name: mongo-4.2
      image: mongo:4.2.2
      networks:
        - mongo-rs0
      ports:
        - 27017:27017
      restart: "always"
      entrypoint: [ "/usr/bin/mongod", "--bind_ip_all", "--replSet", "rs0", "--port", "27017"]
      volumes:
        - /usr/local/var/mongodb:/data/db
```

Unfortunately the container does not recognise the existing databases and the only way I could make it work, it was to create a new folder with the copied files from `/usr/local/var/mongodb` and then map the container volume to the new folder.

The logs for the container:

```sh
mongo-4.2  | 2022-02-21T10:58:05.633+0000 I  CONTROL  [main] Automatically disabling TLS 1.0, to force-enable TLS 1.0 specify --sslDisabledProtocols 'none'
mongo-4.2  | 2022-02-21T10:58:05.657+0000 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=1 port=27017 dbpath=/data/db 64-bit host=ba67b12f98d7
mongo-4.2  | 2022-02-21T10:58:05.657+0000 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] db version v4.2.2
mongo-4.2  | 2022-02-21T10:58:05.657+0000 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] git version: a0bbbff6ada159e19298d37946ac8dc4b497eadf
mongo-4.2  | 2022-02-21T10:58:05.657+0000 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.1.1  11 Sep 2018
mongo-4.2  | 2022-02-21T10:58:05.657+0000 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] allocator: tcmalloc
mongo-4.2  | 2022-02-21T10:58:05.657+0000 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] modules: none
mongo-4.2  | 2022-02-21T10:58:05.657+0000 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] build environment:
mongo-4.2  | 2022-02-21T10:58:05.657+0000 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distmod: ubuntu1804
mongo-4.2  | 2022-02-21T10:58:05.657+0000 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distarch: x86_64
mongo-4.2  | 2022-02-21T10:58:05.657+0000 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten]     target_arch: x86_64
mongo-4.2  | 2022-02-21T10:58:05.657+0000 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] options: { net: { bindIp: "*", port: 27017 }, replication: { replSet: "rs0" } }
mongo-4.2  | 2022-02-21T10:58:05.662+0000 I  STORAGE  [initandlisten] Detected data files in /data/db created by the 'wiredTiger' storage engine, so setting the active storage engine to 'wiredTiger'.
mongo-4.2  | 2022-02-21T10:58:05.662+0000 I  STORAGE  [initandlisten] wiredtiger_open config: create,cache_size=3467M,cache_overflow=(file_max=0M),session_max=33000,eviction=(threads_min=4,threads_max=4),config_base=false,statistics=(fast),log=(enabled=true,archive=true,path=journal,compressor=snappy),file_manager=(close_idle_time=100000,close_scan_interval=10,close_handle_minimum=250),statistics_log=(wait=0),verbose=[recovery_progress,checkpoint_progress],
mongo-4.2  | 2022-02-21T10:58:06.525+0000 I  STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger message [1645441086:525218][1:0x7f30b877db00], txn-recover: Recovering log 27 through 28
mongo-4.2  | 2022-02-21T10:58:06.575+0000 I  STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger message [1645441086:575816][1:0x7f30b877db00], txn-recover: Recovering log 28 through 28
mongo-4.2  | 2022-02-21T10:58:06.607+0000 I  STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger message [1645441086:607702][1:0x7f30b877db00], txn-recover: Main recovery loop: starting at 27/2944 to 28/256
mongo-4.2  | 2022-02-21T10:58:06.608+0000 I  STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger message [1645441086:608358][1:0x7f30b877db00], txn-recover: Recovering log 27 through 28
mongo-4.2  | 2022-02-21T10:58:06.839+0000 I  STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger message [1645441086:839198][1:0x7f30b877db00], txn-recover: Recovering log 28 through 28
mongo-4.2  | 2022-02-21T10:58:06.863+0000 I  STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger message [1645441086:863547][1:0x7f30b877db00], txn-recover: Set global recovery timestamp: (1645210721,1)
mongo-4.2  | 2022-02-21T10:58:06.871+0000 I  RECOVERY [initandlisten] WiredTiger recoveryTimestamp. Ts: Timestamp(1645210721, 1)
mongo-4.2  | 2022-02-21T10:58:06.880+0000 I  STORAGE  [initandlisten] Starting OplogTruncaterThread local.oplog.rs
mongo-4.2  | 2022-02-21T10:58:06.880+0000 I  STORAGE  [initandlisten] The size storer reports that the oplog contains 92 records totaling to 12123 bytes
mongo-4.2  | 2022-02-21T10:58:06.880+0000 I  STORAGE  [initandlisten] Scanning the oplog to determine where to place markers for truncation
mongo-4.2  | 2022-02-21T10:58:06.882+0000 I  STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger record store oplog processing took 1ms
mongo-4.2  | 2022-02-21T10:58:06.887+0000 I  STORAGE  [initandlisten] Timestamp monitor starting
mongo-4.2  | 2022-02-21T10:58:06.888+0000 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten]
mongo-4.2  | 2022-02-21T10:58:06.888+0000 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: Access control is not enabled for the database.
mongo-4.2  | 2022-02-21T10:58:06.888+0000 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] **          Read and write access to data and configuration is unrestricted.
mongo-4.2  | 2022-02-21T10:58:06.888+0000 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: You are running this process as the root user, which is not recommended.
mongo-4.2  | 2022-02-21T10:58:06.888+0000 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten]
mongo-4.2  | 2022-02-21T10:58:06.905+0000 I  SHARDING [initandlisten] Marking collection local.system.replset as collection version: <unsharded>
mongo-4.2  | 2022-02-21T10:58:06.913+0000 I  STORAGE  [initandlisten] Flow Control is enabled on this deployment.
mongo-4.2  | 2022-02-21T10:58:06.913+0000 I  SHARDING [initandlisten] Marking collection admin.system.roles as collection version: <unsharded>
mongo-4.2  | 2022-02-21T10:58:06.913+0000 I  SHARDING [initandlisten] Marking collection admin.system.version as collection version: <unsharded>
mongo-4.2  | 2022-02-21T10:58:06.918+0000 I  SHARDING [initandlisten] Marking collection local.startup_log as collection version: <unsharded>
mongo-4.2  | 2022-02-21T10:58:06.934+0000 I  FTDC     [initandlisten] Initializing full-time diagnostic data capture with directory '/data/db/diagnostic.data'
mongo-4.2  | 2022-02-21T10:58:06.939+0000 I  SHARDING [initandlisten] Marking collection local.replset.minvalid as collection version: <unsharded>
mongo-4.2  | 2022-02-21T10:58:06.940+0000 I  SHARDING [initandlisten] Marking collection local.replset.election as collection version: <unsharded>
mongo-4.2  | 2022-02-21T10:58:06.948+0000 I  REPL     [initandlisten] Rollback ID is 1
mongo-4.2  | 2022-02-21T10:58:06.950+0000 I  REPL     [initandlisten] Recovering from stable timestamp: Timestamp(1645210721, 1) (top of oplog: { ts: Timestamp(1645210751, 1), t: 3 }, appliedThrough: { ts: Timestamp(0, 0), t: -1 }, TruncateAfter: Timestamp(0, 0))
mongo-4.2  | 2022-02-21T10:58:06.950+0000 I  REPL     [initandlisten] Starting recovery oplog application at the stable timestamp: Timestamp(1645210721, 1)
mongo-4.2  | 2022-02-21T10:58:06.951+0000 I  REPL     [initandlisten] Replaying stored operations from { : Timestamp(1645210721, 1) } (exclusive) to { : Timestamp(1645210751, 1) } (inclusive).
mongo-4.2  | 2022-02-21T10:58:06.951+0000 I  SHARDING [initandlisten] Marking collection local.oplog.rs as collection version: <unsharded>
mongo-4.2  | 2022-02-21T10:58:06.955+0000 I  REPL     [initandlisten] Applied 3 operations in 1 batches. Last operation applied with optime: { ts: Timestamp(1645210751, 1), t: 3 }
mongo-4.2  | 2022-02-21T10:58:06.959+0000 I  SHARDING [initandlisten] Marking collection config.transactions as collection version: <unsharded>
mongo-4.2  | 2022-02-21T10:58:06.962+0000 I  CONTROL  [LogicalSessionCacheRefresh] Sessions collection is not set up; waiting until next sessions refresh interval: Replication has not yet been configured
mongo-4.2  | 2022-02-21T10:58:06.963+0000 I  SHARDING [LogicalSessionCacheReap] Marking collection config.system.sessions as collection version: <unsharded>
mongo-4.2  | 2022-02-21T10:58:06.963+0000 I  NETWORK  [initandlisten] Listening on /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock
mongo-4.2  | 2022-02-21T10:58:06.963+0000 I  NETWORK  [initandlisten] Listening on 0.0.0.0
mongo-4.2  | 2022-02-21T10:58:06.963+0000 I  NETWORK  [initandlisten] waiting for connections on port 27017
mongo-4.2  | 2022-02-21T10:58:06.965+0000 I  CONTROL  [LogicalSessionCacheReap] Failed to reap transaction table: NotYetInitialized: Replication has not yet been configured
mongo-4.2  | 2022-02-21T10:58:06.984+0000 I  REPL     [replexec-0] New replica set config in use: { _id: "rs0", version: 1, protocolVersion: 1, writeConcernMajorityJournalDefault: true, members: [ { _id: 0, host: "mongo1:27017", arbiterOnly: false, buildIndexes: true, hidden: false, priority: 10.0, tags: {}, slaveDelay: 0, votes: 1 } ], settings: { chainingAllowed: true, heartbeatIntervalMillis: 2000, heartbeatTimeoutSecs: 10, electionTimeoutMillis: 10000, catchUpTimeoutMillis: -1, catchUpTakeoverDelayMillis: 30000, getLastErrorModes: {}, getLastErrorDefaults: { w: 1, wtimeout: 0 }, replicaSetId: ObjectId('620fb69eddc61b9381ec58c6') } }
mongo-4.2  | 2022-02-21T10:58:06.984+0000 I  REPL     [replexec-0] This node is mongo1:27017 in the config
mongo-4.2  | 2022-02-21T10:58:06.985+0000 I  REPL     [replexec-0] transition to STARTUP2 from STARTUP
mongo-4.2  | 2022-02-21T10:58:06.985+0000 I  REPL     [replexec-0] Starting replication storage threads
mongo-4.2  | 2022-02-21T10:58:06.987+0000 I  REPL     [replexec-0] transition to RECOVERING from STARTUP2
mongo-4.2  | 2022-02-21T10:58:06.987+0000 I  REPL     [replexec-0] Starting replication fetcher thread
mongo-4.2  | 2022-02-21T10:58:06.987+0000 I  REPL     [replexec-0] Starting replication applier thread
mongo-4.2  | 2022-02-21T10:58:06.988+0000 I  REPL     [replexec-0] Starting replication reporter thread
mongo-4.2  | 2022-02-21T10:58:06.988+0000 I  REPL     [rsSync-0] Starting oplog application
mongo-4.2  | 2022-02-21T10:58:06.988+0000 I  REPL     [rsSync-0] transition to SECONDARY from RECOVERING
mongo-4.2  | 2022-02-21T10:58:06.999+0000 I  ELECTION [rsSync-0] conducting a dry run election to see if we could be elected. current term: 3
```

Is there any way to this without the need to create a copy of the files, and map the volume to the existing databases on `/usr/local/var/mongodb`?

Thank you for your time!

Comment: `Unfortunately this doesn't work` is not an error description. What is the logged error or unexpected behavior when running it? Might be a problem with access rights in the folder, docker mongo is using a non-root user which does not necessarily have the same rights as mongo service running at host.

Comment: You're right. I added some container logs and explained better why it is not working. Thank you for your feedback.

Comment: `[LogicalSessionCacheReap] Failed to reap transaction table: NotYetInitialized: Replication has not yet been configured` means that your Replication is not configured. I wonder why it is working with copied folder then.. whats the log telling then at this position? Is it working with no replica (`version: '2.x'`)? How did you run mongod in homebrew replica-wise?